# In Mediawiki, between PAGENAME, PAGENAMEE and urlencode, which one is actually stored in the Page table?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

In the pages I've checked, they all return the same thing, but the Mediawiki documentation says there are differences.

I'm not worried about the differences, but which one is actually stored in the page table?

Comment: The relevant manual page is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:PAGENAMEE_encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of them. The internal representation ("DB key form") is title without namespace (it's stored separately as a number in `page_namespace`), spaces replaced with underscores. The code is [here](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/includes/Title.php#L511). Thus it's neither `{{PAGENAME}}` which is human-readable title, nor `{{PAGENAMEE}}` which is `{{#urlencode:{{PAGENAME}}}}` with special case for spaces -> underscores.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Got it.  I saved the page "Texas A & M" and in the page table it shows as "Texas_A_&_M".</strike>

According to Mediawiki's Manual:PAGENAMEE_encoding page (I can't post more than two links), PAGENAME is the only one that will convert an ampersand to & while the others convert it to %26.

The following is still not correct!

<strike>I thought it was PAGENAME, but PAGENAME actually doesn't replace the spaces with underscores.</strike>

Instead, I found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Title.php) and [here](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/1.25.5/php/classTitle.html) that you can access the string that is stored in the Page table by using this:

`$dbk = $title->getDBkey();`

That snippet is pulled straight from Mediawiki code.

It doesn't appear there is a Magic Word associated with this key.

I can't find where the `page_title` in the database comes from, but it looks like it's simply the page name with the spaces, quotes, and ampersand replaced.  Maybe it's database dependent.  I'm using MySQL.